# Image not visible on IE8 or older

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have an image that scales accordingly to the window size. It works well on IE9+, Chrome, Safari and Firefox but it doesn't appear on IE8 or older.

HTML code:

```
<div class="home_main">
    <img src="main_blur.jpg"/>
    <div class="text_and_button">
        <p>Some text</p>
        <p> more text</p>
        <a href="Contacts.php" class="contact_button">Button text</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS code:

```
.home_main {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 31%;
    float: left;
    height: 0;
}

.home_main img {
    min-height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}

.home_main p {
    padding: 30px 50px 20px 50px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background: rgb(66,91,122);
    background: rgba(66,91,122,.6);
    font-size: 54px;
    font-family: BebasNeue;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Also the paragraphs should have a colored background and the menu on the top of the page don't appear.

You can check the problem on [www.mediata-sa.pt](http://www.mediata-sa.pt).

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: can add display:block;

Comment: @AlexWilson Just tried your solution and the problem persists.

Comment: Why do you have `height: 0;` on the container? I removed this is and it didn't make a noticeable difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DOCTYPE` of your website is `XHTML 1.0 Strict` which means that every element in the DOM must be closed.

Your `<img>` isn't - that will only work in HTML5.  Also in XHTML the `<img>`-tag needs `height="" width=""` attributes which can cause the error in IE8. Don't worry about your CSS, this will overwrite the inline attributes from you `<img>`.

Try `<img src="XXX" height="XXX" width="XXX alt="XXX" />`.

**Edit**

It also seems like IE8 doesn't like `height: 100%;` on images, which is why it's not shown. This fixed the problem for me:

```
.home_main img {
    height: auto;
}
```

**Edit2**

The background of your `<p>`-tags are transparent because CSS says so ;) Right now the values are `background: none transparent scroll repeat 0% 0%` which is equal transparent. In Chrome I can see that you use `rgb();` and `rgba();` for the `background`, which can't be displayed in IE8 as it's CSS3.

In IE8 colors must be CSS2 Standard like only HEX or keyword colors.

```
.home_main p {
    background: blue; // IE8 fallback
    background: rgb(66,91,122);
    background: rgba(66,91,122,.6);
}
```

Comment: I changed the attributes on img as you said but the problem is still there.

Comment: the image is visible now. On the other hand the text should have a background color and I'm unable to see the top menu (I updated question). Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the DOCTYPE from

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
```

to `<!DOCTYPE html>`

The current html in IE8 goes in IE5 quirks document mode. Which when updated with the new doctype work fine.

This should solve the problem.

Comment: Share a working link so I can debug the issue in IE8.

Comment: I just added the link to the question.

Comment: Try updating the DOCTYPE with <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: I don't understand your sugestion. I already have <!DOCTYPE html>.

Comment: This is not true. Just having html as the doctype is still a valid doctype in IE8 and does not cause quirksmode.

Comment: The doctype on the given link is xhtml1-strict.dtd. Which forces the site to open in IE5 quirks document mode. Once the doctype is changed to <!DOCTYPE html> the site document mode is detected properly in ie8. Have tested it and working fine.

Comment: I just changed DOCTYPE and the image still doesn't display properly on IE8.